# Flowchart Generator

Tags: javascript, generator, flowchart

I'm not sure if the Question belongs here - if not, please tell me where I the right place for such Questions is.

I'm currently designing an online API-Documentation for a js-Software which parses Textfiles.

Each line of the Textfile is one "command", and the syntax of each command has to be described.

**This is an example for the output, I want to generate:**

[image: Output]

**The input, which generated this diagram, looks as follows:**

```
CREATE [ UNIQUE | BITMAP ] INDEX [ schema. ]index
  ON { cluster_index_clause
     | table_index_clause
     | bitmap_join_index_clause
     } ;
```

This example is from the Oracle SQL-Documentation, and I wonder if there's a **tool** which makes this kind of diagram automatically? Maybe even written in Javascript?

Comment: Generally speaking, "find a tool" kind of questions are off-topic here but... I've always found those Oracle graphs funny and I'm really curious. I'm sure that any plotting library can generate such graphs (in theory) but an answer with specific tips can be very helpful.